# how to display coordinates on map and draw arrow between them?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have a list of coordinates of real positions as following:

```
index    X              y
1    24050.0000    123783.3333
2    24216.6667    123933.3333
3    24233.3333    123950.0000
4    24233.3333    124016.6667
       .................
```

these are latitude and longitude, given in decimal form (rather than minutes and seconds). taken from [the source](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/)

I want to design a web page on which display the map, on the map show these places by their index. 
Also I want to draw arrows between them (1-->2),(2-->3),...., like that.

How can I do that?

Does it require too much work or is there a simple way?

Please point out the simplest way if you know how to do it.

I am using Javascript.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you specifically need them to be arrows or could them be just lines?

Comment: What coordinate system are those "real positions" in? They aren't compatible with the WGS84 coordinate system required by the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow

Comment: @geocodezip I added the source of data. I don't know what kind of coordinates they are. do you know a way to convert it and can be used in google api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a polyline and then assigning an arrow icon to it.

```
// Here you create the map

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

//Here are the coordinates of the points you are going to match

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];

//Here you create the polyline and assign the arrow icon to it

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
```

Information was taken from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow

I hope this helps you out